# Programatcally remove margin from FrameLayout with LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, classcastexception, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout that looks like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

          // other stuff


     </RelativeLayout>
```

However when I change the margins programitcally I get a ClassCastException.

```
        FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frag);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fl.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0);
        fl.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Here is how I am trying:

```
        FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frag);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fl.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0);
        fl.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Here is `LogCat`:

```
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.---.---/com.------.---.MainFragmentActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at com.---.---.MainFragmentActivity.onCreate(MainFragmentActivity.java:81)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
04-25 16:18:08.385: E/AndroidRuntime(27682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
```

I don't understand how the `RelativeLayout` is involved here?

Comment: Is that due to snippet or mistake in your code that FrameLayout has closing tag of RelativeLayout?

Comment: @Adil  Mistake.  It is fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LayoutParams` class is dictated by the parent, not the child. The `LayoutParams` that affect the `FrameLayout` is a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. The `LayoutParams` that affects the *child* of the `FrameLayout` would be a `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Thanks, by changing it to `RelativeLayout` the parent fixed it,